# Loading a series of text files at matlab

Tags: matlab

I started learning Matlab a few days ago, and I don't know how to load data.

I want to load a series of txt files named as I00001.txt~I09999.txt

I think I should use a loop, using something similar to  %06i format in a sprintf.

But I don't know how to apply that on txt file name.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should consider to accept the answer in case it solve your problem or add a comment in the answer or edit your question in case it wasn't what you were looking for. With this you show to the community if your question has been solved or if it still needs to be answered by other users

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to just find the txt-files using `dir`. It supports wildcards. For example '*.txt' to find only files ending with .txt

```
d = dir('I*.txt')
for ct = 1:length(d)
    name=d(ct).name;
    %do what you want with the file
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert an integer to string with format in Matlab use something like:

```
sprintf('%06i',loopIterator)
```

https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94860-how-do-i-add-leading-zero-to-integer-string-in-matlab-7-8-r2009a

To concatenate strings, to add the initial "l" and the final ".txt" use:

```
s = strcat(s1,...,sN)
```

https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html

All together will result in something similar to:

```
name = strcat('l', sprintf('%06i',loopIterator), '.txt')
```